# Where is the east exit in "Now you see it?"

Tags: antichamber

The problem is not solving the puzzle, I'm wondering where is the puzzle I have to solve?

Comment: Which exit don't you have? The north exit, the west exit, or the east exit?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I can't find the one in the east.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding the east exit *is* the puzzle in the room. In order to go out the east exit, you have to

> grab the block without the door leaving your field of view and then use it to open the door.